# Interval of convergence of a power series, with a check for convergence at endpoints

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Find the interval of convergence of the power series. Be sure to include a check for convergence at the endpoints of the interval. 
>   $$(a) \ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n} \qquad (b) \ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^n}{n\cdot 5^n}$$

I know you use the power series and start with ratio test , test the points at the end. Here is my work so far. Does it look like I am doing the right thing for B? (The solution for A is in an answer)

[image]

[image]

Comment: So far i tried the ratio test. I posted my results

Comment: Does it look like I am doing the right thing for B? Thanks

Comment: When you factor $-1/5$ out of absolute values, you should be taking the absolute value of this, making it $\frac{1}{5}|x-5|<1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point you can factor $x$ from your expression to obtain

$\displaystyle |x| \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left| \frac{n}{n+1}\right|$.  You should be able to find this limiting value.

At that point, you know that the series converges when this expression is less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I believe this is the answer for the first problem. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Your solution for (a) is nearly correct.  You correctly compute the limit in the Ratio Test and give the correct bounds on $x$.  For when $x=-1$ you don't get an alternating series, though, since $(-1)^{n}\cdot (-1)^{n} = (-1)^{2n} = 1$ for all $n$.  So this is just the harmonic series which doesn't converge.  It is the alternating series you give when $x=1$ though, so it converges there.